# pie chart of co-presence in clusters for about 10 factors in r

Tags: r, grouping, data-representation

I've got a two-column dataset with about 30000 clusters and 10 factors like this:

```
cluster-1 Factor1
cluster-1 Factor2
...
cluster-2 Factor2
cluster-2 Factor3
...
```

And I would like to represent the co-occurrence of factors in the clusterset. Something like "Factor1+Factor3+Factor5 in 1234 clusters", and so on for the different combinations. I thought I could so something like a pie chart, but with 10 factors, I take there can be too many combinations.

What would be a good way of representing this?

Comment: It might be quite some combinations, but maybe a stacked barchart would be a solution and I´d probably flip it, but that's just a matter of taste: http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_bar.html

Comment: This is't a programming question, so strictly speaking off topic on StackOverflow.  This might be more appropriate for CrossValidated (stats.stackexchange.com) where they discuss statistics and data visualisation.

Comment: There is a recent question on CrossValidated that is applicable here as well, http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/17734/1036. Piotr's answer could be adapted to this use case. So could the par set's chl suggests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* one good programming question in here that should be addressed:

**How do I count the number of co-occurrences of factors in the different clusters?**

First simulate some data:

```
n = 1000

set.seed(12345)
n.clusters = 100
clusters = rep(1:n.clusters, length.out=n)

n.factors = 10
factors = round(rnorm(n, n.factors/2, n.factors/5))
factors[factors > n.factors] = n.factors
factors[factors < 1] = 1

data = data.frame(cluster=clusters, factor=factors)
```

```
> data
  cluster factor
1       1      6
2       2      6
3       3      5
4       4      4
5       5      6
6       6      1
...
```

Then here is the code that could be used to tabulate the number of times each combination of factors occurs in the clusters:

```
counts = with(data, table(tapply(factor, cluster, function(x) paste(as.character(sort(unique(x))), collapse=''))))
```

This can be represented as a simple pie chart, for example,

```
dev.new(width=5, height=5)
pie(counts[counts>1])
```

[image]

but simple counts like this are often most efficiently displayed as a sorted table. For more on this, check out [Edward Tufte](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edward_Tufte).

Comment: Thanks. May I ask for an example on how to use sorted tables for data like this?

Comment: You can do `data.frame(Count=sort(counts, dec=T))` and then truncate it to only show combinations that appeared in >0 or maybe >1 clusters.